Is there a trick to getting Route53 to work with a subdomain that begins with an underscore?
I'm trying to setup DKIM CNAME records in AWS Route53, but they aren't working due to an underscore at the start of a subdomain. I've tried adding the record to Route53 zone for xyz-domain, for example:
record: fm1._domainkey
value: fm1.xyz-domain.dkim.fmhosted.com

When queried from CLI using nslookup I get:
Laptop:dir user$ nslookup fm1._domainkey.xyz-domain
Server:     192.168.XX.Y
Address:    192.168.XX.Y#53

** server can't find fm1._domainkey.xyz-domain: NXDOMAIN

I've been able to solve this by creating another Route53 zone for _domainkey.xyz-domain and delegating this with an NS record in the  zone. Then records work of the form:
record: fm1
value: fm1.<domain>.dkim.fmhosted.com

I feel this is a rather kludgy workaround though, and would like to avoid having this additional Route53 zone.

I always thought that underscores were invalid in domain names.

@larsks underscores are invalid in hostnames, but pretty valid in DNS otherwise. You can put underscores or whatever symbols into DNS, if they aren't going to be used as some end-system hostname. Indeed, DKIM uses a record name like selector._domainkey.example.com — with underscore, as per RFC 6376. Other examples in DNS are SRV records, which use something like protocol-name._tcp.example-com SRV data data.... It is valid to name a zone with underscore or whatever other symbol is forbidden to be used in a hostname — if that zone isn't going to hold any end system names.
